# Simulate a split washer getting tightened down

Tags: animation

I was hoping for some advice on how to animate a split washer being screwed down tightly. I've modeled the thread, nut and split washer and animated them. However, I need to split washer to flatten against the surface as it gets tightened down. The meshes thickness shouldn't change but it should no longer bend in the z-axis.

[image: Picture of Split Washer]

Comment: You can use shapekeys to make the deformation and animate the shapekey value when the washer is flattened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up your bones first to line up around the shape

Select the object first then the armature and CTRL-P and set automatic weights
[image: Parent to Armature]
The bone you see selected, just move the Z axis up and down or however you please. Make sure Auto IK is enabled
[image: Auto IK and animate]

Comment: Because i only have one rep point i couldn't post more than 2 pictures but just make sure the bones line well around the shape and are centered.

Comment: Just so you know, it would probably make more sense for your comment to be added to the answer. The comments are more for suggestions from other people, not a place for the original poster to add extra information about their post. I would recommend editing your post to include that information.

Answer (score 7):

The method I'm using is very easy to animate; however you have to model the washer using the [screw modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/screw.html).

This is the mesh for my washer. It is just those selected edges on the right in the image below. Notice the placement of the mesh relative to the object origin (it's the orange dot in the red box).
[image: washer in edit mode]

It is the screw modifier that actually generates the whole washer (it is displayed in wireframe in the image above.)

The most important setting is the *Screw*, think of that as the offset. The bigger that number the farther apart the beginning will be from the end. Set it to whatever makes your washer look correct, mine is ¼ of an inch.
[image: screw modifier settings]

#### Now to animate this thing

It is the "*Screw*" value that gets animated to squash the washer.
To set a keyframe, hover over the *Screw* value in the modifier and press <kbd>`I`</kbd>. Or you could <kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd> on the *Screw* value then choose *Insert Keyframe*.

Now move ahead in the timeline, set the *Screw* value to `0` (the washer will be flat) and insert another keyframe, same as the first one.
[image: animated gif - setting the keyframes in the modifier]

[image: animated gif of a bolt, nut and split washer]