# Create spiral out of circle

Tags: modeling

I want to create a spiral that looks like this:

[image: Spiral]

From green to purple is one "circle", but the green part is below the purple. This circle repeats below and so on

Actually it just a circle (pie chart) that is cut at a radius line and then "drawn down" so there results a spiral if you add multiple of these circles.
Does someone have an idea how to achieve this kind of model?

Comment: Maybe you can get some tips from here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77233/simulate-a-split-washer-getting-tightened-down, screw modifier and simple deform taper could work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a simple mesh composed of only one edge progressing along the X or Y axis.

Add a *Screw* modifier to it, adjust properties as desired, mainly the *Steps* for smoothness, *Screw* for height, and *Iterations* for number of turns.

[image]

To assign different colors to your mesh you will have to apply the modifier though, then create multiple *Material Slots*, assign them to the desired faces, then create your colors as desired.

[image]

[image: Final result]