# How to draw an edge

Tags: mesh

I saw an answer to a question in "How to make a spiral out of a circle" ([Create spiral out of circle](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80420/create-spiral-out-of-circle)), in which the person with the answer starts by drawing a single edge from the origin to a point along the X axis. (Please refer to the first answer to the question).

What are the exact steps to draw a single edge, starting at the origin and extending along one of the axes? Many thanks, and sorry in advance for such a simple question! (I tried extruding a point, and also creating an edge between two points, among other solutions, but nothing has worked so far).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can just add a plane and delete two vertices.

Or

- Enable the Add Mesh Extra Objects addon. You can add an object that has a single vertex.

  - Then enter edit mode and extrude that vertex to get an edge.
    or
  - select the vertex and click while holding the <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> key to create a new vertex (and an edge) that are connected to the active vertex.

Or

- Add any mesh object. Enter edit mode and delete all vertices. Then <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> Click to create a new vertex and extrude or create an edge by <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> clicking.

Comment: Many thanks! (For some reason, I must've been doing something wrong and wasn't able to extrude when I tried before, but now it's extruding fine).

Comment: The answer is correct but I believe its a RMB click. So, you have to add a single vert, select vert, hold control and RMB to start drawing them out.

Comment: You realize that the question was asked quite a long time ago? In earlier versions Blender used RMB for selecting, so I guess back in those days it worked with LMB (not that anybody mentions left or right in the answer).